# Finding ILogger messages in ApplicationInsights

Tags: azure-application-insights

I was under the impression that `ILogger` messages from C# go to ApplicationInsights, but I can't find them.

I know my IdentityServer isn't configured with the right redirect URLs. Running locally I'd get an error message on the console.

I've deployed to Azure and should be getting this message -- identity server redirects to its error page as expected.

[image]

How can I find the error message in ApplicationInsights? Or is that not what ApplicationInsights does?

(The application is set up with a `APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY` and `APPLICATIONINSIGHTS_CONNECTION_STRING` and data appears to be accumulating in it -- just nothing of any use.

I need to look at the stuff written out from `ILogger`. Can ApplicationInsights do that? How? Or do I need to look at some other log sink?

[image]

**Edit**

Something has turned up but it's useless as there are no log messages.

[image]

Comment: Have you looked at the `traces` table? Or the `exceptions` table?

Comment: Nothing in `exceptions`, and `traces` is full of more junk; no sign of any log messages. Double checked that `services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry()` is called.

Comment: Well, anything logged using an `ILogger` implementation ends up in the `traces` table, but so does a lot of messages like from asp.net itself. The customDimensions field of the trace might contain a property called category than can be used to track down messages related to Identify Server

Comment: Added custom middleware with a `logger.LogCritical` and the message appears locally in the terminal window, but no sign of it in ApplicationInsights. Are you sure that you're definitely supposed to get the logger messages in ApplicationInsights -- the evidence suggests that this is untrue? There's a strange message: `AI: Local storage access has resulted in an error (User: )....`

Comment: How is you app hosted? Azure function, web app?

Comment: It's a React and webAPI project that I deploy from VisualStudio to an App Service in a linux AppServicePlan.

Comment: Looks like the appsettings seciton `Logging.ApplicationInsights` is _required_. Next problems: when I add an `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string,object>>` as a scope it comes out as the `ToString()` of the `IEnumerable` not as proper keys and values, and ApplicationInsights isn't using the `operation_id` to reassemble the individual output into meaningful traces.